# Database as a Service for use with JavaScript

Tags: database, paas

I'm looking for a database service which will allow me to store and retrieve data from javascript ajax calls. I was thinking it will be a really good way to reduce the load from my server, and I will be willing to pay good money for such a service.

So I searched, and couldn't find anything to my satisfaction. I checked out [Heroku Postgres](https://postgres.heroku.com/) and also [monohq](https://www.mongohq.com/home) but I don't think it's quite what I need.

Do you know of such a service?

Answer (score 4):

[JayStack](http://jaystack.com) offers JayStorm, which is a **Platform as a Service** for JavaScript business apps. This has much more features compared a DB as a service and offers standard-based communication protocols and formats (REST, AJAX, OData, XML, JSON) to consume the data stored in **MongoDB**. The opensource [JayData library](http://jaydata.org) is the recommended tool to consume the service from JavaScript.

You are able to access manage data from **JavaScript, .NET, Objective-C (iOS), Java (Android), LightSwitch** and implement **custom server-side business logic** in JavaScript. The service can be used in zero-code scenarios as well (creating the DB with point-and-click and open the tables from Office Excel).
As the Open Edition is free, you can evaluate the service or run your open-source app without any financial investments :)

I would take a look to [JayStack](http://jaystack.com/blog) and [JayData](http://jaydata.org/blog) DEV blogs.

One of the coolest stuff: leaving the Open Edition means the ability to create new apps on a scalable dedicated virtual server.

Querying your endpoint from JavaScript can be achieved using this snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://include.jaydata.org/datajs-1.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydata.js"></script>
    <script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydataproviders/oDataProvider.js"></script>
    <script>
        $data.service('yourServiceUrl', function (contextFactory, contextType) {
            var context = contextFactory();
            //you can work with this OData context 
            context.Categories.toArray(function (items) {
                console.log(items);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

There are relational DB as a service providers (Windows Azure and [database.com](http://database.com)), but I haven't tried these from JavaScript.

Disclaimer: I'm member of the development team and want to share the technical details.